# Django: Removing duplicated data in model

Tags: django, api, view, model, duplicates

I am getting a data directly from an API and store it in list in dictionary format and then loads the data into the database , but whenever i open that page the data gets duplicated even tho i am clearing the list in the end. I am getting the data in inter_list that is in JSON format, then i convert it to dictionary and find the desired key value pairs using for and if and then i put them in a list. That i then use to populate database.

```
inter_list = response.text
   inter_list = parse_conf(inter_list)
   inter_list = inter_list['dataplane']
   count = 0
   for a, b in inter_list.items():
       for c, d in b['vif'].items():
           for ifkey, ifvalue in d.items():
               if 'description' in ifkey:
                   description = d[ifkey]
               if 'address' in ifkey:
                   address = d[ifkey]
               # else:
               #     address = '-'
               if 'disable' in ifkey:
                   disable = d[ifkey]
               else:
                   disable = '-'
               if 'firewall' in ifkey:
                   firewall_in = d[ifkey]['in']
                   firewall_out = d[ifkey]['out']
           sl.append({
               'vif': c,
               'description': description,
               'address': address,
               'firewall_out': firewall_out,
               'firewall_in': firewall_in,
               # 'color': color,

           })
   for a in sl:
           data = customer(vif=str(a['vif']), customer_name=a['description'], ips=str(a['address']),
                    firewall_in=str(a['firewall_in']),
                    firewall_out=str(a['firewall_out']))  # , current_color=str(a['color']))
           data.save()
```

Comment: It's difficult to help without seeing the code that you're using, and a sample of the data. Please share those.

Comment: @solarissmoke kindly have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to take a step back and see if you really want to save all that data in the DB on every iteration? Maybe there are a few values which needs to be saved for your processing and rest don't. What are you trying to achieve here, what is your logic?